# MouseWheel Event On ComboBox Triggers KeyDown Event

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

Create a Windows Form (Net Framework or Net Core) and add a Toolstrip with ToolStripComboBox control. And then add these methods:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
}
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //any code here;
}
```

If Form *KeyPreview = false* then *Form1_KeyDown* event is not triggered with MouseWheel event on ToolstripComboBox. Setting *KeyPreview = true* (is necessary) causes MouseWheel event is captured by Form1_KeyDown handler as *Up* or *Down*.

Is there a way to prevent *Form_KeyDown* handler **Not To Handle MouseWheel** event?

Comment: For me when I scroll using mousewheel event is not being fired for keyDown when it's just a form. But it happens for combox

Comment: KeyUp/KeyDown keys are actually directed to the internal TextBox of the ComboBox class. You could override `ProcessCmdKey` instead of handling the KeyDown event of a Form, check whether `Control.FromHandle(msg.HWnd) is null` (it will be null for non-.Net Controls) and just `return false` in this case (to let the destination Control process the Key). Handle any other Key when  `Control.FromHandle()` returns a non-null Control (the recipient Control).

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate between source of senders for Up/Down Events catched in `Form_KeyDown` handler whether it comes from `ComboBox MouseWheel` or a  `Up/Down of User Keyboard`, thanks...

Comment: As mentioned, override `ProcessCmdKey`: `msdg.HWnd` is the handle of the Control that will receive the message. The `KeyDown` event is related to your Form, so is the `sender` object.

Comment: in both case HWnd message is `msg=0x100 (WM_KEYDOWN) hwnd=0x213be wparam=0x28 lparam=0x1500001 result=0x0`, no difference btw keyboard Up/Down or MouseWheel...

Comment: Also mentioned: the difference is the handle of Control that will receive the message. When you use the Mouse Wheel in a ComboBox, the recipient Control is not a .Net Control, it's a Win32 `Edit` Control, hence `var ctrl = Control.FromHandle(msg.HWnd)` will return `null`. Now you know the messages are not for a Control of yours, so you `return false` and let it go (you don't handle that KeyUp/KeyDown message -- returning `false`, you let the recipient Control receive the current message. If you return `true`, the message is not sent).

Comment: also `if (sender.GetType().Name == "ToolStripComboBoxControl) ..."` would be of help w/o removing `Form1_KeyDown` in existing code, thanks @jimi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both using comments here as source and referencing vs code knowledge, one solution to this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(dynamic sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType().Name != "Form1")
    {
        //code for action...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

coming here with the same problem, please code like this to differentiate:

```
ActiveControl.GetType().Name != "ToolStripComboBoxControl"
```